# Getting pod or deployment annotations from Kube-State-Metrics

Tags: kubernetes

My Deployment and Pods have specific annotations:

**Deployment Annotations:**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.owners: 'owner1@example.org,owner2@example.org,owner3@example.org'
```

**Pod Annotations:**

```
metadata:
      annotations:
        pod.owners: 'owner1@example.org,owner2@example.org,owner3@example.org'
```

I cannot create labels for these because labels have a size limit of 63 characters and they do not allow special characters like ",". (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#syntax-and-character-set)

I have a kube-state-metrics pod which scrapes all the metrics from kube-api. However, in kube-state-metrics/metrics, I do not see the `deployment.owners` or `pod.owners` annotations anywhere. I see `kube_namespace_annotations` metric, but I do not see any annotations related to deployments or pods.

Are annotations information not captured by kube-state-metrics? How do I get those info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotation information are not collected by kube-state-metrics. You can check their documentation to see which metrics are collected for the resources. Here, are link for documentation about `Deployment` and `Pod` metrics,

1. [Deployment Metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/master/Documentation/deployment-metrics.md)
2. [Pod Metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/master/Documentation/pod-metrics.md)

Comment: Thanks. Not including the annotations is a bit frustrating.